# Traveling to out of EU with refugee travel document

Tags: poland, brazil, refugees, turkish-citizens

I live in Poland with refugee status. I know that I am free to travel within Europe with my permit and travel document. What about traveling to South America?

I am originally from Turkey, and Turkey allows me to travel to Brazil without a visa. But what about where I am now? I don't have a passport from Turkey, but I have a refugee travel document issued by Poland. Can I travel to Brazil (to visit a friend for 15 days) without a visa?

Comment: I can try a phone call to the brazilian embassy in Warsaw to settle it

Comment: In general, to benefit from a visa exemption based on nationality, one must prove that nationality by presenting a passport issued by the country of nationality.  Some countries give visa-free access to refugees (perhaps depending on the country that issued their refugee travel document), but that is a different matter.

Answer (score 4):

According to Timatic, the database used by airlines to check what documents are required, you need a visa for Brazil, a refugee travel document is not enough.

You are correct that Turkish citizens can enter visa free, but you would need a passport issued by Turkey (and getting and/or using one would jeopardize your refugee status).